# Windows 10 update messed up grub

Tags: boot, 14.10, grubrescue

I am using a dual boot laptop with 14.10 and Windows 10. After Windows update, first reboot got me to `grub rescue>` prompt. I have checked previous posts how to force boot into Linux. In all those cases by progressively searching through partitions people found their Linux partitions. My problem is I can't seem to find it.

This is what I get after `set` and `ls` commands.

[image]

It seems before the update boot partition was msdos6. Now I check every partition (msdos1, msdos2 and msdos5) with ls command to find the partition with grub but get `error: unknown filesystem.` for all of them.

```
ls (hd0,msdosX)/boot/grub
```

I will use a live CD to recover as last option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/

I'm afraid I have to recommend the last option. Boot-repair is very easy to use, the automatic option is usually enough

Another way is to start Ubuntu with Supergrubdisk  http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/
And repair grub from the terminal

Comment: With the boot-repair I was able to boot into Ubuntu. It was totally automatic. Thank you. Unfortunately, I lost the Windows partition. Spent couple of hours with testdisk to recover but failed. Even win. recovery disk could not find its partition. I don't understand how an update become such a mess. Anyways

Answer (score 2):

You've probably been hit with the notorious **Windows 10 Anniversary Update**. This update is known to sometimes wipe out Linux/Ubuntu partitions (why? only Microsoft knows). If you can post a current-window-only screenshot of gparted, I can confirm this case.

Recovery, short of reinstalling Ubuntu, can be difficult, but it may be possible through the use of the **testdisk** application. Search AskUbuntu for "testdisk" to read what others experience is.

To run **testdisk**, you need to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD and install testdisk. Once booted, you open a terminal window and type the following three commands, one at a time. Suggest copy and paste.

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install testdisk`
3. `sudo testdisk`

For a step-by-step intro to recovery using testdisk, visit http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step.

Comment: First I tried to recover with testdisk. It gave me the list of partitions correctly. Located my Linux partition and set as primary boot. After reboot back to grub recovery and this time msdos5 was missing. So I decided to try with boot-repair before I mess up more. I got me into ubuntu. Thank you.